# How to build the Url parameter in the geomesa accumulo raster store of geoserver

Tags: raster, geoserver, geomesa

I've been trying unsuccefully to use the geomesa accumulo raster driver from geoserver. There is not documentation for encoding the connection parameter Url. I tried to use the one generated using the class org.locationtech.geomesa.raster.wcs.AccumuloUrl with the parameters tested correctly but geoserver raise an error, invalid URL. In the source code of the module geomesa-accumulo-raster there is nothing (example, test, comments, ...) that give me light on solving this problem. 
The page in geomesa documentation is wrong (https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-raster.html) assuming that there are fields to fill as in vector data store. The only field to fill has a URL format and there is not documentation to form it.

Is someone using it that can help me.

Thanks in advance,

Capote

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the geoserver module [here](https://github.com/geomesa/geomesa-geoserver/tree/master/geomesa-gs-raster), which is packaged separately due to licensing. Once you install that JAR, the page will show the fields as expected.

edit: Documentation on this is [here](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/accumulo/raster.html#geoserver)

Comment: I am using the geoserver within the geodocker project to ingest and publish raster images. This geoserver already includes the plugin to publish vector data sources and, as you said, the raster extension was not included. I already built and included the raster extension and everything is working fine. Thank you very much for the help.